# Looping through a table without knowing it column names in oracle

Tags: oracle

I’m dealing with a table that is created dynamically, i.e. it has different number of fields and different field name each time it is created. How can I deal with it with out knowing its field names?
for example

```
  for FieldValue in (select * from PAYROLL_POVIT)
  loop
      csvLine := null;
      for FieldName in (select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='PAYROLL_POVIT')
      loop
          csvLine := csvLine || FieldValue.FieldName.COLUMN_NAME
      end loop;  
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(csvLine);
  end loop;
```

or something like

```
for FieldValue in (select * from PAYROLL_POVIT)
  loop
      csvLine := null;
      for i in 1..(select count (*) from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='PAYROLL_POVIT')
      loop
          csvLine := csvLine || FieldValue.COLUMN(i)
      end loop;  
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(csvLine);
  end loop;
```

Thank you

Comment: Tables should not need to be created dynamically.  Doing so indicates a serious design flaw in the application.

Comment: Thank you EdStevens. The created table a result from povit table for each employee. Each time it is created, it will has differnet columns depending on employees departments. Furthermore, the table is flat and died, it is for reading purposes only.

Comment: I've been working with oracle since versin 7.3, around 1995, and I've never heard of a table "flat and died".  How could a 'pivot table' be different in structure based on a selection criteria. Sounds like all you need is a view.

Comment: I agree with Ed Stevens. If you and your organization know that the table is "dead" (it is certainly brain dead), create a better data model and export the data from the "old format" to the proper data model. Stop writing queries against the old model; you will only run into performance and maintenance problems all the time (worse: you will create wrong output very easily, and without even noticing it).

Answer (score 0):

I managed. Here is the solustion

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PAYROLL_CSV
IS 
  csvLine clob;
  MySQL VARCHAR2(100);
  MySQLResult VARCHAR2(500);
  fileHandler UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  fileHandler := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('ORACLE_DIRECTORY', 'myfile.csv', 'w');
  csvLine := null;
  for FieldName in (select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='PAYROLL_POVIT')
  loop
      csvLine := csvLine || FieldName.COLUMN_NAME || ',';      
  end loop;
  UTL_FILE.put_line(fileHandler, csvLine); -- File Header
  
  for FieldValue in (select * from PAYROLL_POVIT)
  loop
      csvLine := null;
      for FieldName in (select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='PAYROLL_POVIT')
      loop
          MySQL := 'select "' || FieldName.COLUMN_NAME || '" from PAYROLL_POVIT where PAYROLL_RECID = ' || FieldValue.PAYROLL_RECID;
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE MySQL INTO MySQLResult;
          csvLine := csvLine || MySQLResult || ',';
      end loop;  
      UTL_FILE.put_line(fileHandler, csvLine); -- Row Data
  end loop;
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fileHandler);
  
EXCEPTION
  WHEN utl_file.invalid_path THEN
     raise_application_error(-20000, 'ERROR: Invalid path for file or path not in INIT.ORA.');
END;
```